Modules jdk.xml.dom and xercesImpl export package org.w3c.dom.html to module io.cucumber.core.gherkin.messages'
Within one of my projects I used the following dependency:
<dependency>
  <groupId>xerces</groupId>
  <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
  <version>2.12.2</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
      <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>

with the following module-info.java:
open module de.powerstat.fb.mini
 {
  exports de.powerstat.fb.mini;

  requires transitive java.xml;

  requires org.apache.logging.log4j;
  requires transitive de.powerstat.validation;

  requires transitive org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient;
  requires org.apache.httpcomponents.httpcore;
  requires org.apache.commons.codec;

  requires com.github.spotbugs.annotations;
  requires org.junit.jupiter.api;
  requires org.junit.jupiter.params;
  requires org.junit.platform.launcher;
  requires org.junit.platform.suite.api;
 }

I got the following error message:
[INFO] --- surefire:3.5.0:test (default-test) @ miniapi ---
[INFO] Using auto detected provider org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[WARNING] Corrupted channel by directly writing to native stream in forked JVM 1. See FAQ web page and the dump file C:\MyProject\target\surefire-reports\2024-09-28T15-18-12_539-jvmRun1.dumpstream

Within the mentioned file there are the following messages:
Stream 'Error occurred during initialization of boot layer'.
Stream 'java.lang.module.ResolutionException: Modules jdk.xml.dom and xercesImpl export package org.w3c.dom.html to module io.cucumber.core.gherkin.messages'.

When looking through my dependencies I found:
jdk.xml.dom:
org.w3c.dom.css
org.w3c.dom.html
org.w3c.dom.stylesheets
org.w3c.dom.xpath

as well as:
xercesImpl-2.12.2.jar:
org.apache.*
org.w3c.dom.html

Which means that we have a split package here which is not allowed within the java module system.
Any idea for a workaround? Or maybe xerces is unusable with the java module system?
Would Saxon be a replacement that works with the java module system? Or is there any other solution?

Check whether you still need Apache Xerces. These days I think the version of Xerces that's built in to the JDK probably does all that you need.

Thanks to the hint of Michael Kay it seems to be enough to remove the xerces dependency when using newer Java versions like 17:
<!--
<dependency>
  <groupId>xerces</groupId>
  <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
  <version>2.12.2</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
      <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
-->

